# Facebook API targeting only canada

Tags: facebook

I am having some trouble getting the FB api's targeting feature to work. I want to target only Canada but I can't seem to figure out what the documentation is asking of me. This is what I have tried

```
  FB.api(
    '/' + pageId + '/live_videos',
    'POST',
    {access_token: accessToken,
    description: document.getElementById("streamDescription").value,
    title: document.getElementById("streamName").value,
    targeting: {excluded_countries: ["840"]}
    }
```

currently this is outputing

```
"(#100) The targeting param has invalid values for: excluded_countries"
```

Comment: You need to specify either `geo_locations` or `locales` inside the `targeting` object ... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/page/feed#publish

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it

```
  FB.api(
    '/' + pageId + '/live_videos',
    'POST',
    {access_token: accessToken,
    description: document.getElementById("streamDescription").value,
    title: document.getElementById("streamName").value,
    targeting:{geo_locations:{countries:["CA"]}}
    }
```